# Hive Table retention support

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to support retention on a Hive table for old partitions. Basically I need to automatically delete Hive partitions after a specific period. I can manually do this or with a script but I have noticed that a retention property exists in every Hive Table but I can't find many information about it.

For example when using descibe in a hive table there is a retention property

```
desc formatted my_hive_table;
>>>
col_name                data_type                comment
...
Retention:              0                        NULL
...
```

and I have found this 2014 [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7025) but I am not sure if it is implemented and how.

Can anyone confirm if Hive supports this capability and if yes how to configure it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's available in Hive 3, at least it's in HDP since 3.1.4
See configuration here https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/using-hiveql/content/hive-set-partition-retention.html

Comment: Do you know in which CDH version is this also availiable?